# Where to install gulp?

Tags: node.js, configuration, installation, gulp

I'm trying to leverage from Elixer so I started to get up and running. I've installed Node and Npm. Later I also installed Gulp using `sudo npm install gulp -g`. But this installed Gulp in my project directory, resulting in a massive file transfer from my local host to the webserver. Is it necessary to install Gulp inside the project directory? Or is there a better way to install it somewhere else and use it for any project needed?

Sorry if this is a total beginners question but I can't seem to find an answer online. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only few steps to start use it.

1. Install globally `$ npm install --global gulp`
2. Install directly to your project root dir `$ npm install --save-dev gulp`
3. Create `gulpfile.js` in root dir

Then in your new gulpfile do the follow:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});
```

and after that just type `gulp` command in terminal to execute default task

here is documentation to help you started with gulp [docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) and here you can find packages to use it [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/)

Tip: if you on OSX use sudo to install npm/jspm/gulp etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Clear. I'll exclude it from file transfers in my PhpStorm project then. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

`Gulp`, `bower`, ... are dependencies.

The command `npm install ...` will download the module to the directory named `node_modules`. They need to be (litterally) a part of your project. Think of it as a pure JS library (as it actually is).

Answer (score 1):

`sudo npm install gulp -g` shouldn't be installing gulp in your project directory. However, Gulp does **always** need to be installed locally in the project folder in order for it to work. Otherwise, you will get an error when trying to run Gulp. The `-g` global installion of Gulp is only needed for linking the shell to the binary `$ gulp`; it will dispatch to the local gulp program as soon as it is called.